# Invariant subspace problem for $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, invariant-subspace

Is the invariant subspace problem known for $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ or for more general $L^2$ spaces, i.e. does every bounded linear operator $T \colon \ell^2(\mathbb{N}) \to \ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ have a non-trivial (closed) T-invariant subspace?

Comment: Every separable Hilbert space is isometrically isomorphic to $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$. Based on that, what would you be able to conclude?

Comment: Thanks! I somehow forgot about this (so my question is equivalent to the invariant subspace problem (for non separable Hilbert spaces one can easily construct a non trivial invariant subspace)). How can I close the question (or do I have to delete the question or do you want to write this as an answer?)

Comment: It is okay for you to write an answer, and then select it as an answer. In fact, it is encouraged because you are here to find answers. It will be a good thing to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is, we don't know.

The invariant subspace problem is known for non separable Hilbert spaces and for finite dimensional ones, e.g. see [this answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/922402).
As noted by Disintegrating By Parts, every infinite dimensional and separable Hilbert space is isometrically isomorphic to $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$.

Hence, the question is equivalent to asking whether every bounded linear operator $T \colon \mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}$ has an non-trivial invariant subspace, where $\mathcal{H}$ is a separable Hilbert space.